# Zebra ZQ620 ^FO command don't move origin

Tags: android, zebra-printers

I have some issues printing labels on a Zebra ZQ620 bluetooth, with ZPL commands. Some of them don't work as expected. I use Android and Zebra's SDK with the next code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Instantiate insecure connection for given Bluetooth MAC Address.
            Connection thePrinterConn = new BluetoothConnectionInsecure(getcBTMAC());

            // Initialize
            Looper.prepare();

            // Open the connection - physical connection is established here.
            thePrinterConn.open();

            // This example prints a label.
            String zplData = "^XA" +
            "^FO530,10^ATR,36,20^FD  Sheet: 9999/LA    Lbl.: 1    S/R: 3333^FS" +
            "^FO470,10^ADR,72,30^FD" + "  123456. THIS IS A BIG TEXT" + "^FS"+
            "^FO420,10^ATR,36,20^FD" + "  BarCode: 2139EJC   28/09/2021   Total: 6 u.^FS\n"+
            "^FO300,300^B3R,N,100,N,N^FD2139EJC^FS" +
            "^XZ";

            // Send the data to printer as a byte array.
            thePrinterConn.write(zplData.getBytes());

            // Make sure the data got to the printer before closing the connection
            Thread.sleep(500);

            // Close the insecure connection to release resources.
            thePrinterConn.close();

            Looper.myLooper().quit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle communications error here.
            Log.e("PRINT", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

The label is printed partly good (rotate as required and text displayed), but the next commands don't work as expected:

- ^FOx,y: I can move origin in "x" axis (width) but "y" axis value is ignored and all text is printed from bottom to top. It doesn't matter what value I put in "y" value. It always is ignored. Then, I can move origin of text y this axis.
- ^B3R,N,100,N,N: It ignores all parameters I put. I changed height to 100, 200, 300, include or not line text. It is always ignored. I have added a ^BY3 command previously, and It changes width but not height. Barcode is printed with only 2mm of heigth and I can't set it bigger.
- ^ADR,72,30: All fonts command ignore scales.

Printer configuration is:

- Commands: ZPL (I have tried ZPL II, hibryd_xml_zpl, epl_zpl).
- Labels: 76mm (width) x 101 mm (height) . Label separator: black mark line and space between labels.

Comment: I've tried your ZPL and it works fine. Im changing the ^FO parameters aswell as ^B3R and it changes correctly. You can always test your ZPL here http://labelary.com/viewer.html I think there is an issue with your Java code. Do you always print that one label as in the code you provided or do you change some parameters?

Comment: I have tried some examples that comes with Zebra Programmig Guide (basic examples - pages 35 and 36), and some other combinations of commands without success. My java code is copy-paste from Zebra SDK examples, and It works, almost, It sends all commands to the printer. Some commands works and some not.